# Leading up to subclause with "was"

Tags: grammar

> Man lernt mehr aus dem, was schiefgeht, als aus dem, was klappt.

Is it possible to rephrase this using *daraus* or *woraus*?

> (a) Man lernt mehr daraus, was schiefgeht, als daraus, was klappt.
>
> (b) Man lernt mehr woraus, was schiefgeht, als woraus, was klappt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that "was" refers to "dem".

It would be no problem to use "daraus" if you replace "was":

> Man lernt mehr draus, *wenn etwas* schiefgeht, als daraus, wenn etwas klappt.

To use "woraus" seems impossible to me. According to Duden, "woraus" is used when questioning what something is made of:

> "Woraus ist das gemacht? Seide"

Or if refering to something:

> Es ist nichts im Hause, woraus ich einen Teig machen könnte.

Comment: Jap. "Woraus" zu verwenden ist schwer, aber man kann eben eine 'Frage' formulieren: "Die Antwort auf die Frage, woraus man mehr lernt, ist eindeutig, wenn etwas schiefgeht als wenn etwas klappt."

Answer (score 0):

The sentence contains two determinative pronouns ( a combination of demonstrative and relative pronoun):

1 das, was schiefgeht

2 das, was klappt.

And you have to maintain these pronouns even if you change the case.

Your use of daraus+was is not idiomatic and woraus+was is wrong.